# Filtering Pinecone vector database by user id

Tags: python, flask, langchain, pinecone

I'm having an issue with being able to filter the vectors in my Pinecone index by user ID. The way I initially though to set this up was that my chat function for take in the user id from the route then pre-filter only by vectors with that user ID.

```
@app.route('/<int:user_id>/chat', methods=['POST'])
def chat(user_id):
    user_message = request.form.get('message')
    
    # Load the conversation history from session
    conversation_history = session.get('conversation_history_{user_id}', [])

    index_name= os.getenv("PINECONE_INDEX")
    index = pinecone.Index(index_name)

    vectorstore = Pinecone(
    index, embeddings.embed_query, text_field
)
    
    bot_temperature = get_bot_temperature(user_id)
    custom_prompt = get_custom_prompt(user_id)

    # Initialize the chatbot with the bot_temperature
    llm = ChatOpenAI(
        openai_api_key=openai_api_key,
        model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo',
        temperature=bot_temperature
    )

    # Define the prompt template with placeholders for context and chat history
    prompt_template = f"""
        {custom_prompt}

        CONTEXT: {{context}}

        QUESTION: {{question}}"""
    
        # Create a PromptTemplate object with input variables for context and chat history
    TEST_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["context", "question"], template=prompt_template)

    # Create a ConversationBufferMemory object to store the chat history
    memory = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True, k=8)

    # Create a ConversationalRetrievalChain object with the modified prompt template and chat history memory
    conversation_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
            llm=llm,
            retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(filter={"user_id": {"$eq": {user_id}}}),
            memory=memory,
            combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": TEST_PROMPT},
        )
    # Handle the user input and get the response
    response = conversation_chain.run({'question': user_message})
    
    # Save the user message and bot response to session
    conversation_history.append({'input': user_message, 'output': response})
    session['conversation_history'] = conversation_history
    
    # print(f"User: {user_message} | Bot:{response}")  # This will print the conversation history
    # print(conversation_history)
    # print(session)
    # print("*"*100)
    
    return jsonify(response=response)
```

I originally thought one could just make separate indexes for each chatbot (my app is basically a RAG pdf reader) then use the userID as the name for that index then swap index name with ID but I believe this would get very expensive.

Comment: With pinecone it might be worth looking into namespaces for each user as opposed to creating a brand new index for each user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter with metadata, save user_id in metadata and search.

```
retriever_m = index.vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={
    'filter': {'source': 'user_id'},
})
```

Comment: This is a solid start and mainly commenting this in case someone stumbles across this, but for some reason the .as_retriever function doesn't like numbers for the filter kwargs. If you use numbers as a metadata and then want to filter by them you will probably have to convert it to a string then turn your number that you are filtering by into a string `retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'filter': {'user_id': f"{user_id}"}})` then my function to process the text which adds the info to the vd would look like this: `process_text(text, filename, page_num,f"{user_id}")`